# gitlab runner docker error al arrancar

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

cuando lanzo el comando para arrancar un gitlab runner con docker

```
root@XXXX:~ # docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always 
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Tengo siguiente error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d2013e29d87d964426e8ecb4395592c86ab06de6540e984a683384fb383dbbb5-init/merged/etc/hostname: invalid argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
root@XXXXX:~ #
```

Siempre obtengo el mismo error y no puedo arrancar el runner para gitlab. No tengo ni idea que puede ser y tampoco he encontrado nada por internet. Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Cuando hago el inspect de la imagen veo que en la imagen del git runner si que esta el directorio del merge definido

```
       "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9ffcfae1d9e580a268c9bc036f508897e0d509c3eaceefdd1eb920094f5ea8e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/71c34194ceb88bfb22aec686f304ad1914eaddea4f4e9930a364366805ede021/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/65861bbe4d6e915f5a648456affc5463fbbda763b8377147aff6fda87de48663/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9391fdf7ad3f812d497c0445a848336b761faadeda3ce79c7254ff0863023e3b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bef96d05605ae31ea8c402251d60c4b1f1ae54491b864dbc481a22f9b18a85b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33f0477042725731e2f5e0604949d084e751b24b35af4c0d5bcc9da1bbf76a8b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cf41c97e89422202ef418769799e57c3ccf633f270124436cdd2de0e8420514/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f8f74b873c3e5216f3f1dc17aed3a0b88d4ac19997d5cfd6ed0eeb7c2d33415/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a15904656a47747b2faf84607394335e51fd84c9c3551b10419516a89fa3fffc/diff",
       "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d/merged",
       "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d/diff",
       "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d/work"
  },
```

Pero cuando voy al path ese directorio no existe, solo existe work y diff

```
root@lmadinttgitss01:~ # cd /var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d
root@lmadinttgitss01:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d # ls
**diff  link  lower  work**
root@lmadinttgitss01:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/06756d645111c6105742e7b20115aac6c3cc178be3059c69dc8f78054bba075d #
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Intenta quitar el `-` de el nombre.

Comment: Gracias Alanfcm, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Qué formato (sistema de archivos) usa tu disco, en particular el montado en /var/lib/docker? ¿Es `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4` ...? (`df -T` te lo puede decir)

Comment: El sistema de archivos es xfs.

Comment: @SPG pues ese puede ser el problema. Véase [la documentación](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/), o [esta issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10294). Ejecuta `docker info` a ver si te da algún aviso.